# How to get like 'next monday' records from mysql database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have database for wordpress. My select box for day like 'monday', 'tuesday'. In wordpress postmata i have two metakey one is 'starting-date' and 'end-date'. User select day so fetech data from next day. like user select 'monday' so all data wii be 'next monday' data.

Comment: Show us your database structure...!!

Comment: What is your date format in DB ?

Comment: You can start by researching about selecting tables in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/retrieving-data.html

Comment: date formate like : 2015-01-05

Comment: My database structure is i have two meta key one is start-date and other is end-date and meta value is date in wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get day of next week by below code //code

```
 echo date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime('next Monday')).'<br>'; –
```